# Working with objects created with Activator.CreateInstance

Tags: c#, reflection

Consider the code below:

```
void fun1(string typeName)
{
    object adap = Activator.CreateInstance(typeName);
    adap.dowork(); //won't compile because of strongly typed.
}
```

Using `Activator.CreateInstance()` we can easily create instance of any type, but if we don't know the typename at design time, it is not possible downcast it to its actual type either.

My question is, how can we call a function of instance created by `Activator.CreateInstance` if we cant downcast it to its appropriate type as we dont know the typename at design time, but we know that the function exists.

I hope I've made myself clear.

Comment: If you don't know the type at compile time than how do you know to call dowork() on it?  Is there a common interface between these types?

Comment: Typically this is done with interfaces.  You have an abstract interface (that acts as a "contract" that shouldn't change that much) and you take a dependency on that but not a specific implementation.  You can then get at members of the implementation via the interface.

Comment: Yes, You are absolutely right, this is typically done through Interfaces or Inheritance but I cannot use them in my case because I am not the one who is creating the "Type" whose object needs to be created.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One thing you can do is assign it to a `dynamic` type.

```
dynamic adap = Activator.CreateInstance(typeName);
adap.dowork(); //this now compiles
```

It is also possible to invoke a method dynamically using reflection if you know the method name.

Answer (score 3):

The best option is to know some common interface or base-class, and cast to that. However, if that is not possible you can duck-type by using

```
dynamic adap = ...
```

And the rest of your code as-is.

If that isn't possible (wrong .net version etc) then you'll have to use reflection.

Answer (score 0):

If you know that `typeName` has the method `doWork`, it would be better that your type implements an interface like:

```
interface IDoWorkSupport
{
    void DorWork();
}
```

then you can make your code like:

```
var adap = (IDoWorkSupport) Activator.CreateInstance(typeName);
adap.DoWork(); //this now compiles
```

In this case its a more object-oriented solution.